# Unrecognized keyboard layout after login

Tags: unity, gnome, keyboard, lightdm, keyboard-layout

Two of my computers running Ubuntu randomly ignore the configured keyboard layout and fall back to *qwerty*.

On one computer the configured layout is "Français" (French), on the other it is a bépo (dvorak-like layout for French). On both computers the layout was selected at installation time in order to make it the default system-wide. On both computers the login screen always uses the right layout. It's only once that the user is logged in that the keyboard starts working as a *qwerty*

One computer uses *LightDM* and *Unity*, the other uses *GNOME Display Manager* and *GNOME 3.8*. The problem occurred with *Ubuntu 14.04* and is still in *14.10*.

So far I tried to erase my `~/.gnome*` and `~/.config` directories and to reinstall the system, without success. I have also ensured that the session settings were copied in the system settings in the control panel.

Do you have any hint to solve this problem?

**Edit:** also, even if the layout is incorrect in the session, it is still correct in a terminal opened with `ctrl+alt+F1`.

Answer (score 0):

try running :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration
```

you will see a command-line configuration screen like this (sorry, French version) :

[image: screen capture]) :

Use keyboard UP and DOWN to select the correct options, TAB to switch over "OK" or "CANCEL" and ENTER to move to the next screen.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a keyboard priority issue. On Unity dash, search for "System settings" then open: `System settings > Text Entry`. Then use the ^ arrows to move up the layout you want to be the default keyboard layout. Make sure that your preferred keyboard layout is number one on that list. I would also suggest that you also remove all keyboards layout(s) you don’t need/use, use the - and - buttons to add or remove keyboard layouts respectively.

Then next time you restart you systems the changes should take effect.